# retrieve data from database based on closest date to today

Tags: php, sql, pdo

in my website, when the user clicks a button it takes them to a page and retrieves data from the database that has a date column, and display the data in a div dynamically and it displays a button that deletes the row if it has a date in the future or it's today's date, the problem is it's displaying the retrieved data based on what's entered in the database first, so you'll find some divs without the delete button first then the divs with the delete button, i want the divs that has the delete button (has a future date or today's date) to be displayed first, preferably the closest date to today then the divs without it, how can i do that?

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM info WHERE phone = :phone");
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone',$_SESSION['phone']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row=$stmt->fetchAll();
    
   
    
   if($row)   
   { ?>
       // irrelevant echos from database
             
       <p> date: <?php echo $stmt["date"];?></p>

       
       <?php if(date("Y-m-d") <  $stmt["date"] )
             {?>
            
              <button class="delete-button" name="formSubmit" value="delete">Delete</button>
                  
             <?php } 
             ?>
   }
```

Comment: use `ORDER BY date DESC` in the query. Do you know about ORDER BY in SQL?

Comment: oh i do, but i had no idea i can use it to desc based on a specific column i have *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ORDER BY date DESC
```

in the SQL query. This will sort by the date, with the most recent first.

```
SELECT * FROM info WHERE phone = :phone ORDER BY date DESC
```